# JPA: Indexing by another field of a table referenced by a foreign key

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

I'm using JPA through the Play Framework, with Mysql.

Let's say I have a JQL query as follows:

```
SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.address.city = 'New York'
```

The address field is a foreign key reference to an Address table.

My understanding is that this query will require a table scan of the entire Person table, "dereferencing" the "address" field, and then doing a scan of the Address table too.  Even if the city field on the Address object is indexed, we're still looking at a scan of the entire Person table.

I'd like to make this query fast by somehow creating an index on p.address.city in the Person table, is this possible in JPA/MySql?

Comment: Did you found sollution?

Answer (score 2):

I believe so, if you are using Hibernate you can use their annotation

```
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Table(
     name="table_name",
     indexes = { @Index(name="idx_", columnNames = { "xxx", "xx" } ) }
     )
```

or `@Index` annotated in your column (placed in model) from the `org.hibernate.annotations` package

I hope this helps

Comment: Right, that is how you create a simple index, but how do you create an index to a column in a foreign table?

Comment: Well, have you set a relationship? I thought once its within the relation the ORM would set up the indexing automatically, at least when I looked at my schema Hibernate had set it up. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding your question

Comment: I think the ORM will set up an index for the "address" field in Person, which contains the primary key of the Address object.  However, it won't set up an index for the "city" field of the address object in the Person object, so the above query will require a table scan of the Person object.